# q promise nodejs sequence

Tags: node.js, promise, q

I am trying to run a sequence of promises.
I have read the github page of q kriskowal and his example of sequences, but he never used the previous result for the next promise.

```
return foo(initialVal).then(bar).then(baz).then(qux);
```

So my code is:

```
var Q = require('Q');
function foo(arg) {
  console.log('foo arg=' + arg);
  var d = Q.defer();
  bar(arg+1)
    .then(function(){
        d.resolve(arg);
    }, function(error){
        d.reject(error);
    })

  return d.promise;
}
function bar(arg) {
  console.log('bar arg=' + arg);
  var d = Q.defer();
  d.resolve(arg);
  return d.promise;
}

function test() {
  var defer = Q.defer();
  foo('a')
    .then(function (success) {
        var def1 = Q.defer();
        console.dir('success: ' + success);
        bar('test');
    })
    .then(function (rest) {
        return foo('b')
    })
    .then(function(success){
        defer.resolve(success);
    }, function(error){
        defer.reject(error);
    });

  return defer.promise;
}


var b = [test(), test(),test()];

Q.all(b)
.then(function(result){
  console.dir(result);
})
```

The output is:

```
foo arg=a
bar arg=a1
foo arg=a
bar arg=a1
foo arg=a
bar arg=a1
'success: a'
bar arg=test
'success: a'
bar arg=test
'success: a'
bar arg=test
foo arg=b
bar arg=b1
foo arg=b
bar arg=b1
foo arg=b
bar arg=b1
[ 'b', 'b', 'b' ]
```

What I want is:

```
foo arg=a
bar arg=a1
'success: a'
bar arg=test
foo arg=b
bar arg=b1

foo arg=a
bar arg=a1
'success: a'
bar arg=test
foo arg=b
bar arg=b1

foo arg=a
bar arg=a1
'success: a'
bar arg=test
foo arg=b
bar arg=b1
```

Answer (score 0):

By doing this :

```
var b = [test(), test(),test()];

Q.all(b)
.then(function(result){
  console.dir(result);
})
```

You are running test() 3 times in parallel. So it is normal that you get mixed log entries.

If you want to run test() 3 times in series you would do :

```
test().then(test).then(test)
.then(function(result){
  // result is the result of the 3d run
  console.dir(result);
})
```

If you want the results of all runs, change test() so as it accepts an array and pushes result into it when done, then resolves to that same array

```
  function test(results) {
    var defer = Q.defer();
    foo('a')
      .then(function (success) {
          console.dir('success: ' + success);
          return bar('test');
      })
      .then(function (rest) {
          return foo('b')
      })
      .then(function(success){
          results.push(success);
          defer.resolve(results);
      }, function(error){
          defer.reject(error);
      });
    return defer.promise;
  }
```

Then :

```
var resultsHolder = [];
test(resultsHolder).then(test).then(test)
.then(function(r){
  // r === resultHoler
  console.dir(r);
})
```

Comment: Thanks redben for your example. so now it´s more clear.

But how can i run an array of Tasks dynamically in a series

Comment: ``tasks.reduce( function(lastPromise, task) { return lastPromise ? lastPromise.then(task) : task(resultHolder) } ).then(allDoneFunction) ``